# How do I open a Playground inside of Xcode in a project directory?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6, swift-playground

I'm building an iOS with swift. It appears the project template does not have a playground file. I go to File >> New >> Playground >> name my file >> place the playground file inside of my project directory. I look for it in the side bar directory but it is not there. I then go to Finder and navigate to the project and I can see the file.

Should it be showing up on the project directory?

Comment: As the name suggests the playground is for running swift interactively. It is not supposed to an artefact of any project.

Comment: @AnthonyKong actually it was able to come up this time. I created a separate group within the project and created a playground file

Comment: Actually, I take that back.

Answer (score 4):

I am late to answer but it might be helpful for someone else looking around, Its much simple, just open xCode go to **File > Open >** choose the directory where you last time created the playground project and finally choose **fileName.playground** (file with .playgorund extension) and boom it will be your last saved playground project.

Answer (score 1):

With the new Xcode that's out, its much easier.
File --> New --> playground
the dropdown from file leads you to New, that leads you to choose playground, after choose whatever one you are looking to play in.
Good Luck!